# If condition checking for two TextFields Value

Tags: javascript

```
if(a.value === undefined || a.value.length>37 || 
        b.value === undefined || b.value.length > 256) {
```

If the first one is undefined or greater than a length of 37. I get a error, but it does not check for the second field at all.

Comment: Side note: Don't use the `undefined` "constant", as it's not really a constant. Use `typeof a.value === 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting what an OR in logic means. It only going to check until it finds one true statement.

Try regrouping:

```
((a.value === undefined || a.value.length>37)
                   ||
 (b.value === undefined || b.value.length > 256))
```

Just about elevating the condition a bit, and bringing a more broad result back instead of chasing the first true response.

Comment: if one succeeds among them it does not throw error, how can i check if anyone fails in them it should throw error.

Comment: @John Cooper: Use `&&` instead of `||` between the two fields. This will insure that both group 1 & 2's conditions have been met (neither are undefined nor have a length exceeding their limit).

Answer (score 1):

use parenthesis. It checks from left to right and stops once it hits a fail the way you have it set up.
Try

```
if((a.value === undefined || a.value.length>37) || 
(b.value === undefined || b.value.length > 256)) {
```

Comment: just use if(typeof x == "undefined") to see if the variable x is defined. So in this case, it would be a and b instead of x

Answer (score 1):

Conditional evaluation is lazy, i.e. it stops as soon as the result has been determined. That is, `if (A && B)` will *not* evaluate `B` if `A` is false, because the conjunction will have to be false already, and similarly `if (A || B)` will *not* evaluate `B` if `A` is true because the disjunction is already true.